# A limit containing integrals

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ be such that $f \in L^1([-a, a])$ for all $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\lvert f(x) \rvert < C$. Moreover let $h: \mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ be such that $h(x) = 0$ for $x < 0$ and $h \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$.

Let's define two functions

1. $y(t) = \int \limits_{-\infty}^{t} h(t-s)f(s) \, ds$,
2. $z(t) = \int \limits_{0}^{t} h(t-s)f(s) \, ds$.

---

I would like to show that
$$\lim \limits_{t \to \infty} \lvert y(t) - z(t) \rvert = 0.$$

---

I tried to solve that problem dividing the interval $(- \infty, t)$ into two segments: $(-\infty, 0)$ and $[0, t)$. Thus
$$\lvert y(t) - z(t) \rvert = \bigg\lvert \int \limits_{-\infty}^{0} h(t-s)f(s) \, ds \bigg\rvert. \tag{1}$$

We can say two things about the expression on the RHS of $(1)$, let's call it $M_t$:

1. $M_t \ge 0$,
2. $M_t \le C \, \big\lvert\int \limits_{-\infty}^{0} h(t-s) \, ds \big \rvert.$

   What arguments can I use to show that $M$ tends to $0$ while $t \to \infty$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're actually nearly there:

Let's perform a simple change of variables $x=t-s$ to get a better grasp of the integral in (2):
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{0} \left| h(t-s) \right| ds =  \int_{t}^{\infty} \left| h(x) \right| dx $$
Now the last integral tends to zero as $t \rightarrow \infty$ basically by what it means to be in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ (For a rigorous proof you could try e.g. the dominated convergence thm.).

Comment: Thanks, that's an important observation. How can I use the dominated convergence theorem here?

Comment: You can rewrite the last integral to be $\int_0^\infty \left| h(x) \right| dx - \int_0^t \left| h(x) \right| dx $. The second term is - in the limit - the way we usually compute integrals strechting over the whole real line and that it works can be prooven in a standard fashion using the dominated or monotone convergence theorem.